# How to change "the require_once" with "get_template_part"

Tags: php, wordpress

Is it possible to change "the require_once" with "get_template_part" ?

On my Wordpress file, I try to change this line:

```
 function upthemes_admin_home() {require_once('home.php');}
```

To be like this:

```
 function upthemes_admin_home() {get_template_part( 'home' ); }
```

But did not work. Anybody, please help.
Thanks for your kindness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you explain "did not work" ? Do you get any message? Also try placing

```
get_template_part( 'home' );
```

in your theme file and check if it's working. I think you know that `get_template_part()` is relative to the active theme directory, so it will check for the file like this :

```
/wp-content/themes/active_theme/home.php
```

Comment: Yes BebliucGeorge. You right, I made mistake with the path. Thanks